# Align a list of variable-size data/text with corresponding labels/text using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to align variable-size data with corresponding labels (regular labels, not form labels) using CSS in order to achieve something like the following:

```
       Name: James Bob
Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
             sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore...
         ID: 007
```

A list? Nested divs? This would be a snap with a table, but tables are always frowned upon for anything but tabular data. I tried with floating divs, but they are a nightmare to join in the center, especially when the labels or data change in length.

Comment: Isn't it kind of tabular data? It's so easy with [tables](http://jsfiddle.net/6sDSx/).

Comment: @Bigood Good question. I'd like to get an opinion on this. Table or layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a layout like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SpsAy/)**?

HTML

```
<div class="l">Name:</div>
<div class="r">James Bob</div>
<div class="l">Description:</div>
<div class="r">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
    nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore...</div>
<div class="l">ID:</div>
<div class="r">007<div>
```

CSS

```
.l {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.r {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try floating the labels to the left and than use `width` or `min-width` for labels

```
<label>Blahblah : </label><input type="text" /><br />
<label>Blahblah : </label><input type="text" /><br />
<label>Blahblah : </label><input type="text" /><br />

label {
   float: left;
   width: 300px; /* You can change this accordingly */
}
```

Comment: No good, multi-line data (i.e. Description) is not justified with the label after the first line (this isn't a form). Also, `label` is missing `text-align:right;`

Comment: @SkyNT If that isn't a form than why you need labels? can't you simply use a table instead?

Comment: That's my initial thought, but I was under the impression, tables shouldn't be used for anything but an actual table, like you'd find in  Excel.

Comment: No here you are wrong, use tables for representing for tabular data and not for designing layouts :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your answer. The example I gave above, to me, is definitely a layout and not a table. Maybe I should wait for more opinions from the community? If we all agree this falls under the category of tabular data, then I think I'll just go that route.

Comment: @SkyNT people will argue until the cow comes home as to whether or not a data entry form is tabular data.  My personal opinion is that the minimum number of records required for tabular data is 1.  As long as each field (td) has a corresponding heading (th), there doesn't seem to be anything inappropriate about using a table this way.